# Modify logrotate defaults on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

Ubuntu 18.04 has default configurations of packages for logrotate in `/etc/logrotate.d`

For example with nginx installed I have a file `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx`

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 14
        [..]
}
```

Where can I modify these settings? Should I just edit the file?

Since I guess this file came with the nginx package I don't want it to overwrite my settings or complain when nginx is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should control `logrotate` by editing files in `/etc/logrotate.conf.d`. First, read `man logrotate logrotate.conf`.

Some packages take special care to preserve user configuration changes, as explained in their `man` pages. `logrotate` is not such a package.

The packaging system has been known to warn that it's about to replace a user-modified configuration file and offer choices (Replace the file, Do not replace the file, Diff the old and new files, Open a shell), but this might depend on the packager marking the file as "configuration".

A System Administration way of maintaining your modified configuration files is to store the modified files in your own, similarly structured directory structure, e.g. `$HOME/.userconfig/etc/logrotate.d/nginx.conf`, and write a simple script to copy the files from `$HOME/.userconfig/` to the system. Run this script after you update the packages.

Beware! If the package changelog says "We changed/improved the configuration file format", stuff may break.